# Jenkins behind a network load balancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, networking, amazon-vpc, nlb

I deployed a Jenkins to an ECS cluster and configured EFS to JENKINS_HOME.
Access to Jenkins is only via the corporate network via AWS Private Link (VPC Endpoint), so I need to use an NLB to access my Jenkins. I can access it over HTTPS (Certified in ACM and linked to NLB), but Jenkins returns HTTP 302 and informing that the URL accessed is in HTTP and I receive a timeout, as I only have valid configuration for HTTPS.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

My Cluster is the type of launch EC2 and for governance reasons I cannot access the machines of the cluster.

Example request:

```
Request URL: https://jenkins.mydomain.com/blue/organizations/jenkins
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 172.168.18.7:443
Referrer Policy: same-origin
```

Response

```
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2020 14:28:16 GMT
Location: http://jenkins.mydomain.com/blue/organizations/jenkins/
Server: Jetty(9.4.30.v20200611)
X-Blueocean-Refresher: f24c80d9
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

My scenario is: On-premises network -> private link -> vpc endpoint -> network load balancer (TLS 443) -> forward Jenkins TPC 8080.

Comment: Are you using TLS termination on your NLB? ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/

Comment: Yes,I forward the traffic to my Jenkins in the cluster using tpc 8080. He responds in the first request, but when entering some other configuration or making a registration, he returns HTTP 301

Comment: I solved this problem using nginx as a reverse proxy. I put them both on the same task and used the Links feature.

In the configuration of ngix, I used the configuration below and it worked perfectly.

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`